# Password generating that starts with uppercase and lower case in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

It should be uppercase and lowercase first.

Then it should be numbers and characters.

Then it should be a mixed of all characters.

```
import random
pswd = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
numbrs = "0123456789"
chars = "@#$&*_-:;',./^"
def pswd_generator(data):
    if data == 1:
       genpswd = "".join(random.sample(pswd,size))
    elif data == 2:
       genpswd ="".join(random.sample(pswd+numbrs+chars,size))
    elif data == 3:
       genpswd = "".join(random.sample(pswd+numbrs+chars,size))
       print "Your Generated Password is:",genpswd
m = False
while not m:
    size = int(raw_input("How many digits of password do you want to generate: "))
    print "1.Weak Password"
    print "2.Medium Password"
    print "3.Strong Password"
    print ("Select 1,2,3")
    data = int(raw_input("Enter the option: "))
    if data == 1:
      m = True
    elif data == 2:
        m = True
    elif data == 3:
        m = True
    else:
        print "Wrong option.Try again"
pswd_generator(data)
```

How can I achieve in pythonic way?

Comment: The code cannot guarantee to suffice your conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clean it up and make it a bit more Pythonic along with meeting the goal of your password requirements I'd suggest the following:

- Change your `pswd_generator` function so that it accepts two arguments, an `option` and `size`.  The reason for this is that you're relying on the `size` variable being created *before* the call to this function...`pswd_generator` is only working because `size` is in the global scope after the `size =`
- Do some very basic error checking in `pswd_generator` to ensure the option being passed in is valid.
- Add spaces in between the arithmetic operators. Readability counts for a lot in Python.
- Return the password from this function. If a function appears to be "generating" something, it should return it to the caller. This has the side benefit of making this function easy to test if you ever wrote unit tests.
- Determine a minimum length for your password...like 6.
- Pick some size for the different groups within your generate password, i.e., the prefix which starts with upper an lowercase, based on the desired length. Do the same thing for the next group. No you'll know how many characters to choose for each group. This is demonstrated below in option 2 for demonstration.

```py
def pswd_generator(option, size):
    assert(option in (1, 2, 3))

    size = max(6, size)
    prefix_size = min(5, size / 3)
    number_size = min(5, size / 3)
    filler_size = size - prefix_size - number_size

    if option == 1:
       genpswd = "".join(random.sample(pswd, size))
    elif option == 2:
       genpswd = "".join(
           random.sample(pswd, prefix_size) +
           random.sample(numbrs + chars, number_size) +
           random.sample(pswd + numbrs + chars, filler_size)
       )  
    else:
       genpswd = "".join(random.sample(pswd + numbrs + chars, size))

    return genpswd
```

For your main loop I'd suggest:

- Changing the `while` condition to simply look at whether a password has been created. The way it's setup now you're using a variable to just break out of the loop...there are simpler ways to accomplish that.
- In order to check for the correct option you can tighten this up by looking for whether the input value is greater than zero and less than four. If it is, set the `psswd` variable which you can then print out and which will also terminate your loop.

```py
psswd = None
while not psswd:
    # stuff

    option = int(raw_input("Enter the option: "))
    if 0 < option < 4:
        psswd = pswd_generator(option, size)
        print "Your Generated Password is: ", psswd
    else:
        print "Wrong option.Try again"
```

Comment: @brianz..Thanks.But i need to get the output starting with uppercase and lowercase then the numbers and symbols then all the mixed characters.               >eg: aOtIjB3#0$8^y4@F!&e,                                                                                
!

Comment: @hai_v I've updated the answer to meet that requirement.